# Regression not running in R when?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to run the following code:

```
library("quantmod")

audchf30=getFX("AUD/CHF", from = Sys.Date()-30, to = Sys.Date())
eurusd30=getFX("EUR/USD", from = Sys.Date()-30, to = Sys.Date())

reg <- lm (audchf30 ~ eurusd30, data=dat)
summary(reg)
```

The idea behind the program is that I gather a certain number of observations for both currency pairs, and run a standard OLS regression between them. However, when I attempt to run the regression I get the following error messages:

```
**> reg <- lm (audchf30 ~ eurusd30, data=dat)**
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'dat' not found

**> summary(reg)**
Error in summary(reg) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': Error: object 'reg' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. For some reason you don't have to assign value to "audchf30". Function getFX("AUD/CHF") creates XTS object with name AUDCHF. Which you can transform to dataframe.

```
getFX("AUD/CHF", from = Sys.Date()-30, to = Sys.Date())
getFX("EUR/USD", from = Sys.Date()-30, to = Sys.Date())

dat <- data.frame(AUDCHF, EURUSD)

reg <- lm (AUD.CHF ~ EUR.USD, data=dat)
summary(reg)
```

Comment: Or you could set `auto.assign=FALSE` to the `getFX` calls: `audchf30 <- getFX("AUD/CHF", auto.assign=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first error says that you do not have an object named "dat" loaded in the environment. The two objects you create in the second and third lines need to be put in a data.frame named dat:

```
dat <- data.frame(audchf30=getFX("AUD/CHF", 
                           from = Sys.Date()-30, to = Sys.Date()),
                  eurusd30=getFX("EUR/USD", 
                           from = Sys.Date()-30, to = Sys.Date()))
```

Your regression code should run after this.